# Inferring ThisType in function inside object literal

Tags: typescript

Using a self referential `ThisType` in an object literal works as expected. The typescript compiler is ok with accessing properties defined in the object and emits error messages when trying to access undefined properties.

```
function define<A>(options: A & ThisType<A>) {}

define({
  a() {},
  w1: function () {
    this.a(); // ok
    this.b(); // error
    return () => {
      this.a(); // ok
      this.b(); // error 
    };
  }
});
```

Is there a way to make the typing work the same way with a wrapper function?

```
function wrapper(fn: () => any) { return fn; }

define({
  a() {},
  w2: wrapper(function () {
    this.a(); // should be ok
    this.b(); // should be error
  }),
});
```

This is only a question about typing, at runtime `this` has the correct value and it works as expected.

I tried using combinations of `function` and arrow functions and generic types like `function wrapper<T>(fn: (this: T) => any) { return fn; }` but what should `T` be?

Comment: I don't think this is possible, but I'd be interested in learning otherwise.

Comment: I think it's possible if you use an alternative api, `define((wrapper) => ({ ... }));`, but I wasn't adept enough to make it work. Otherwise, I don't think this is possible.